# Error "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." with module Tkinter

Tags: python

I'm using win 64 python 2.7.12 and when I try using Tkinter it said "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." Uninstall and re-install don't seem to work no matter it's x86 or x64. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: That sounds like a 32 bit / 64 bit incompatibility problem. Is there some reason that you can't use Python 3?

Comment: Yes I have to use python 2.7 version. All I need now is a x64 version of Tkinter

Comment: What does "try using Tkinter" mean? Do you get that error as soon as your script does `import Tkinter`? Are you using python, or some other program that has an embedded python interpreter?

Comment: What happens when you 'import _tkinter'? Is there an error?

Comment: @kabanus import _tkinter and import Tkinter show the same error, "try using Tkinter"  I mean from Tkinter import *

Comment: First thing I should have asked - do you have Tcl/Tk installed?

Comment: Yes I already have tcl 8.5 and tk 8.5